# Как в Android Studio (Kotlin) обратиться к элементу Linear Layout по id и изменить layout_margin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, margin

Я столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Мне необходимо программно изменить расположение LinearLayout на экране, для этого Linear Layout присвоено id (`android:id="@+id/scooterButton"`).
В функции onCreate я пытаюсь обратиться к Linear Layout по ID:

```
val scooter_button_layout: LinearLayout = R.id.scooterButtun
val scooter_button_layout: LinearLayout = findViewById(@id/scooterButton)
```

Попробовал два способа, оба не работают. В первом случае "scooterButtun" горит красным (Unresolved reference: scooterButtun), во втором красным горит "id", кроме того при наведении на закрывающую скобку среда показывает "Expecting an element".

Как через Kotlin присвоить Linear Layout layout_marginStart и layout_marginTop, причём в dp?
Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы найти элемент надо использовать
`val scooter_button_layout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.scooterButtun)`

а варианты, как установить `margin` можете посмотреть здесь
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411634/set-runtime-margin-to-any-view-using-kotlin

Comment: В дополнение к ответу можно добавить, что во избежании ошибки "Unresolved reference" при использовании R.id стоит либо удалить `import android.R`, либо заменить его на `import android.R.id` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58611875/unresolved-reference-in-kotlin-with-id-and-activity-main).